# How to parseInt in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Probably, it is the simplest thing but I couldn't parse a string to Int in angular..

What I am trying to do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="num1">
<input type="text" ng-model="num2">

Total: {{num1 + num2}}
```

How can I sum these num1 and num2 values?

Thnx!

Comment: `{{(num1-0) + (num2-0)}}`, no? But I'd rather use a helper function here.

Comment: That works indeed! Thnx!

Comment: For anyone coming here wondering how to do this JS side, $window.parseInt() is best

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You cannot (at least at the moment) use `parseInt` inside angular expressions, as they're not evaluated directly. Quoting [**the doc**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> Angular does not use JavaScript's `eval()` to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's `$parse` service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   `window`, `document` or `location`. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.

So you can define a `total()` method in your controller, then use it in the expression:

```
// ... somewhere in controller
$scope.total = function() { 
  return parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2) 
}

// ... in HTML
Total: {{ total() }}
```

Still, that seems to be rather bulky for a such a simple operation as adding the numbers. The alternative is converting the results with `-0` op:

```
Total: {{num1-0 + (num2-0)|number}}
```

... but that'll obviously won't *parseInt* values, only *cast* them to Numbers (`|number` filter prevents showing `null` if this cast results in `NaN`). So choose the approach that suits your particular case.

Answer (score 31):

Option 1 (via controller):

```
angular.controller('numCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
   $scope.num = parseInt(num , 10);
}
```

---

Option 2 (via custom filter):

```
app.filter('num', function() {
    return function(input) {
       return parseInt(input, 10);
    }
});

{{(num1 | num) + (num2 | num)}}
```

---

Option 3 (via expression):

Declare this first in your controller:

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

Then:

```
{{parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2)}}
```

---

Option 4 (from raina77ow)

```
{{(num1-0) + (num2-0)}}
```

Comment: somehow I accidentally down-voted this and now it's locked unless the answer is updated... I'm going to add whitespace at the end of the answer so that I can add an up-vote to it

Comment: Option 4 is sweet

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="number" string-to-number ng-model="num1">
<input type="number" string-to-number ng-model="num2">

Total: {{num1 + num2}}
```

and in js :

```
parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2)
```

Comment: This may work, but to be clear,  string-to-number is a suggested directive, not a part of Angular. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt. It allows you to assign string values to numeric input fields. It does not change the actual type

Answer (score 1):

Perform the operation inside the scope itself.

```
<script>
angular.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
$scope.num1= 0;
$scope.num2= 1;


  $scope.total = $scope.num1 + $scope.num2;

 });
</script>
<input type="text" ng-model="num1">
<input type="text" ng-model="num2">

Total: {{total}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.num1 = 1;
   $scope.num2 = 1;
   $scope.total = parseInt($scope.num1 + $scope.num2);

}]);
```

Demo: [parseInt with AngularJS](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/rOdPbr)

Answer (score 0):

**This are to way to bind add too numbers**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.total = function() { 
  return parseInt($scope.num1) + parseInt($scope.num2) 
}
})
</script>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>

<input type="number" ng-model="num1">
<input type="number" ng-model="num2">
Total:{{num1+num2}}

Total: {{total() }}


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside template this working finely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
<input ng-model="name" value="0">
<p>My first expression: {{ (name-0) + 5 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```