# How to convert double into int in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code snippet :

```
<span ng-if="document.size<500" >
    0
</span> 
<span ng-if="document.size >=500 && document.size < 1048576" >
    {{document.size/1024}}
</span> 
<span ng-if="document.size >=1048576" >
    {{document.size/1048576}}
</span>
```

i got document size in byte and then i convert it into KB and MB.
but it gives value in double.
how can i convert it into int in angular js?
can i convert it in int expression directly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: He means convert inside angularjs expression. So it duplicate with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js

Comment: The answer by Janeel Grand gives an exact, concise answer (hot to do it in *angular*), arguably better than the answers linked to by @TaiHuynh, and certainly better than the more general question which this question is marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `floor()`:

```
Math.floor(document.size/1024)
```

Answer (score 16):

```
{{val | number:0}}
```

it will convert val into integer

go through with this link [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it's much cleaner and does not change the value, only its format