# disable a button if a text input is not an integer with ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 text fields.

```
input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name">
input type="text" placeholder="number" ng-model="number">
```

I validate that the button is not active if no data in text fields. I do not know how to make the button is disabled if there is no positive integer in the text field "number".

```
<button ng-disabled="!name || !number" value="buttonTest"></button>
```

I need to be a strictly input type = 'text'

Comment: You could just change the input type to number. Then in your ng-disabled have the expression number < 0

Comment: @Harbinger no, I need to be a strictly input type = 'text' . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="1234" ng-model="number">
    <br/>
    <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!name || !parseInt(number) || number < 0">Button</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WBVMKWYSNBAxmQdg7i2K?p=preview

Comment: I need to be a strictly input type = 'text' , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in your controller to check these values and return the result. I sometimes use the `length` property of strings to determine if there's a value. It covers null, undefined, and empty strings.

```
$scope.isPositiveInteger = function(value) {
    var floatValue = parseFloat(value);
    var isInteger = floatValue % 1 === 0;
    return isInteger && floatValue > 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-disabled="name.length < 1 || !isPositiveInteger(number)" value="buttonTest"></button>
```

Comment: This is the right answer since you can't make the input type a number. The parseInt/Float will not work in an Angular expression on the html which is a shame. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js.  You will have to write code in your controller like @HankScorpio illustrates here.