# convert string to Number in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am showing an array which contains JSON and am directly showing this with HTML, here you can find `elem.fc + elem.cpc`. It's giving NaN as an output.

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr ng-show="table.table1loaded" ng-repeat="elem in filteredcampaignslist" ng-init="initializepopover()">
<td ng-show="app.ostype=='iOS'"><div class="text-center">{{elem.fc+elem.cpc}}</div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this: [How to parseInt in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js)

According to the Angular docs within that post, you cannot, as of the moment, perform such operations within expressions.

The best way to go around this is to create a function that does so within a controller and then bind it to your HTML.

HTML:

```
 <tr ng-show="table.table1loaded" ng-repeat="elem in filteredcampaignslist" ng-init="initializepopover()">
<td ng-show="app.ostype=='iOS'"><div class="text-center">{{ Total() }}</div></td>
</tr>
```

Inside AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.Total = function() { return parseInt(elem.fc) + parseInt(elem.cpc); };
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `{{elem.fc+elem.cpc}}` to `{{+elem.fc + +elem.cpc}}` 
That should do the trick.

Comment: No this trick is not working, I need to subtract values some pleases, but this dosen't works in addition too.

Comment: If it's not working, that can only mean that elem.fc or elem.cpc are not numbers or strings representing numbers. Over to you  to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134133/2945345) for versions 2 and above of angular:

```
Number('1234') // 1234
Number('9BX9') // NaN
```