# AngularJS: is 0 == 2?

Tags: angularjs

I am scratching my head here. I am using angularJS and trying to use the expression that contains call to parseInt.

```
{{0 == 2}}
```

...prints out **false** as expected.)

However, when I am trying:

```
{{parseInt(0) == parseInt(2)}}
```

... it prints out... **true** !

How can this be possible?

Comment: Can you create an [mcve]?

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat ;)

Answer (score 13):

> Angular does not use JavaScript's `eval()` to evaluate expressions.
>   Instead Angular's `$parse` service processes these expressions.
>
> Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like
>   `window`, `document` or `location`. This restriction is intentional. It
>   prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of
>   subtle bugs.

**[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js/26294266#26294266)**

In your html

Both `parseInt(0)` and `parseInt(2)` are undefined in your html.

So `{{undefined==undefined}}` is `true`.Beacause `parseInt` is a `Javascript` function.So you cant access the `parseInt` function in side `{{}}`. [Here parseInt is not a scope variable]

**Solution**

If you wish to do this,

define `parseInt` in your controller,

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

Then you can use the `parseInt` method in your html

Comment: can you see parseInt here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp ?

Comment: This answer will help you,http://stackoverflow.com/a/26294266/3901856

Answer (score 7):

That's because `parseInt` is not defined in your scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

Comment: what you mean by parseInt is not defined?

Comment: can you see parseInt here w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp ?

Comment: He means "parseInt()" as a function is not defined in your scope. `parseInt` is a Javascript function, but within {{ }}, Angular doesn't consider that as Javascript. It maps it to the scope of your controller. Therefore `undefined == undefined` equals true.

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute regular JS in an angular expression. Your expressions will be evaluated against the current scope. So, `parseInt` is `undefined` in the current scope.

If you set `parseInt` as a function reference, it will work.

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the view is attached to the controller via **scope**.

So whatever we write in view either a variable or a function  or anything it's rendered by appending $scope in front of it.

eg.
a is rendered as $scope.a **in the view**

So when we write parseInt, its rendered by $scope.parseInt which is not defined.

**FIX-** define **$scope.parseInt = parseInt** in the controller attached to the particular view

Answer (score -1):

You have comparing both **undefined** values so result will be **true**.

You cannot call a javascript method(parseInt) via angular directives(ng-blur,ng-change,..) either you can achieve by making angular functions.

**Solution 1:**

```
{{0*1 == 2*1}}
```

Just do a trick to convert to Integer by multiply with 1 (0*1 = 0, 2*1 =1).

**Solution 2:**

```
{{parseInt(0) == parseInt(2)}}
```

Controller:

```
// To Convert specific format
$scope.parseInt  = funtion(value){
    return parseInt(value,10);
}
```

or

```
$scope.parseInt  = parseInt;
```

reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Comment: Do elaborate more on the answer, and why it is correct answer, failing which it will be deleted.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you guyz!! for correcting me :-)