# How To Totalsum Two Values In Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to total sum two values in angularjs , actually we have two tables and  I got the total sum values like `124.10` in `convertion rate` then I'M expecting to calculate `convertion rate` totalsum values like `A + B` as a `124.10 + 124.10 answer = 248.20`...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9fJeIZZjU21MwSRv8rd?p=preview).

- We have two table so I want to calculate first table convertion rate total sum value and second table convertionrate totalsum value
- For exmaple:- fisrt table convertion rate is `124.10`, and second table convertion rate is `124.10` , we need to calculate these to value in third table like `A + B` answer should be 248.20.
- I have given the plunker as reference [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9fJeIZZjU21MwSRv8rd?p=preview) please any one knows the solution help us.

**My Controller:-**

```
  .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
})
```

**My Data:-**

```
$scope.sryarndebitnote = [
{
"_id": "57ac1b6d82e1c5940ac3c730",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-08-11T06:30:05.118Z",
"shipment_id": "57ac19b982e1c5940ac3c72f",
"conversion_rate": "62.04",
"invoice_value_fob_currency": "Rs",
"invoice_value_fob": "300.231",
"invoice_quantity_unit": "KG",
"invoice_quantity": "37",
"invoice_date": "2016-08-17",
"supplier_name": "Msd",
"buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
},

{
"_id": "57b5af69df0475401f644b2e",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-08-18T12:51:53.671Z",
"shipment_id": "57b5af5bdf0475401f644b2d",
"conversion_rate": "62.06",
"exclusive": true,
"invoice_value_fob": "400.343",
"invoice_quantity": "97",
"supplier_name": "Msd",
"buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
},]
```

**My Html:-**

```
<tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=(sryarndebitnote)"> 
     <td >{{$index + 1}}</td>
       <td >{{(resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' * 1) + (resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' *1)}}</td>
         </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>sum</td>
            <td>B = {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate'}}</td>

         </tr>
```

- Third table should be `a+b` calculating values and final total sum of `C` value like `A+B` value 248.20 , so the `c` value total sum is `496.40`.
- `c` total sum value `496.40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 <td >{{(resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' * 1) + (resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' *1)}}</td>
```

To this:

```
 <td>{{((resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate')*1) + ((resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' )*1)}}</td>
```

The problem is parenthesis.

Comment: Hey thanks for your valuable comment and answer, we got A+B answer like 248.2 as well , then need totalsum of A+B , for example :- We Expecting C value like 496.4.... any idea or solution ? please....then please update plunker as well to the solution as well...updated plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/7N202S3BldCxZuADLOnY?p=preview ....if we got the total sum of A+B i will give you the tick mark as well...thanks a lot..

Comment: thanks for your answer it's working perfectly... thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

```
{{(resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' * 1) + (resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate' *1)}}
```

Using this kind of tricks to force integer summation is discouraged and you should not use them in sensitive applications.

That being said;
You have to actually force the result from filter to be an integer. e.g:

```
   {{(resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate')*1 + (resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate')*1}}
```

But you really should come up with a more robust approach in this situtation. Even wrapping `parseInt` function in your controller does the trick.

For further reading:

[How to parseInt in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js)

Comment: hey thanks for your valuable comment and answer, we got `A+B` answer like `248.2`as well , then need totalsum of A+B , for example :-  `C` value like 496.4.... any idea or solution ? please....then please update plunker as well to the solution as well...updated plunker:-    http://plnkr.co/edit/RWKE2wESbFhJ4p4WreFZ?p=preview  ....if we got the total sum of A+B i will give you the tick mark as well...thanks a lot..